# Redis starts manually with init.d but not on startup

Tags: ubuntu, redis, init.d

Redis properly starts up if I run the command:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/redis-server start
```

I've added my startup script with:

```
sudo update-rc.d redis-server defaults
```

But when I startup from a fresh boot, Redis isn't running. Where should I look to troubleshoot this?

Comment: In my log files, I can see redis exiting and starting up manually, but nothing is written to the log on startup.  I can see a link to redis-server in each of my /etc/rcX.d/ directories.

Comment: Ubuntu 13.10 (Saucy Salamander)

Comment: Have you installed redis from repo or from sources? It starts normally on my 13.10

Comment: Aha, I had installed from source.  I just removed redis-server from rc.d, reinstalled from the repo and let it replace my init.d/redis-server file, then added it back and restarted.  It started up just fine.  Convert to answer for bounty.

Comment: @arby Did the below answer work for you?

Comment: @Manu I actually had luck after I removed mine with `update-rc.d -f redis-server remove` then ran `apt-get install redis-server` and let it replace my init.d/redis-server script, then added it with `update-rc.d redis-server defaults`.  Everything is working as it should now.

Comment: Interesting. Good to know. But I would personally prefer fine grained control over `defaults`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `defaults` thing usually sets starting to 20. It's too early as redis requires networking.

So, try below:

`sudo update-rc.d redis-server remove`
`sudo update-rc.d redis-server start 80 2 3 4 5 . stop 20 0 1 6 .`

Comment: ``sudo update-rc.d redis_6379 start 99 2 3 4 5 . stop 20 0 1 6 .`` did it for me

Answer (score 3):

Use the below into the terminal:

```
sudo systemctl enable redis
```

It made [redis](/questions/tagged/redis) run on startup for me.

Comment: _sudo systemctl enable redis-server.service_ did it for me

Answer (score 2):

In my case update-rc.d didn't work

```
$ sudo update-rc.d redis-server start 80 2 3 4 5 . stop 20 0 1 6 .
update-rc.d: warning: start and stop actions are no longer supported; falling back to defaults
```

On the other hand

```
sudo systemctl enable redis-server
```

did the trick