# raspbian custom daemon start manually but not on boot

Tags: python, linux, daemon, boot, raspbian

I have created a python script. I set in as a daemon.

When I start manually, it works fine :

> service testMotor start

it works well ! Cool.

Then I wanted to make it works on startup. I follow the tips given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20589725/redis-starts-manually-with-init-d-but-not-on-startup).

So I used :

> update-rc.d testMotor start 99 2 3 4 5 . stop 20 0 1 6

I also tried to move the file in the /etc/rc2.d/K01testMotor to /etc/rc2.d/S99testMotor

But never, never does this daemon start on boot.

What do I do wrong ?

Thanks for any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution :

Just insert a

> sleep 15

before /sbin/start-stop-daemon

And your service will start 15 sec after the boot of the machine.